# How do I sign my wearOS app with the same keystore as my mobile app?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play-console, android-keystore

I have a Java application in Android Studio which includes a mobile and a wear directory. I want both of them uploaded for internal testing, and the mobile app works fine.

I just added an extra release track for the wear app, but when I try to sign it with the generated zip from the pepk tool it says I should upload a valid key and that the uploadkey and implementation key should be different.

I've tried uploading the same zip file used to sign the mobile .aab, and also tried generating a new one with the same keystore. I was told to use the same keystore, but it the signing doesn't seem to work. How do I solve this?